# Need for XEventsQueued(display, QueuedAfterReading) in XCB

Tags: c, xlib, xcb

I am migrating some code of CYBOI from Xlib to XCB.

CYBOI uses a couple of threads for different communication channels like:
serial_port, terminal, socket, x_window_system.
However, it uses these threads only for signal/event/data detection;
the actual receiving and sending is done in the main thread,
in order to avoid any multi-threading conflicts of address space.

For the x_window_system channel, I previously [detected events](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/src/executor/lifeguard/sensor/x_window_system/check_events_x_window_system_sensor.c?revision=2097&root=cybop&view=markup) in a thread:

```
int n = XEventsQueued(display, QueuedAfterReading);
```

Upon detection of an event, an "interrupt flag" was set.
Afterwards, the main thread was [reading the actual event](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/src/executor/communicator/receiver/x_window_system_receiver.c?revision=2097&root=cybop&view=markup) using:

```
XNextEvent(display, &event);
```

When no more events were available, the main thread stopped receiving events
and the x_window_system channel thread started listening with XEventsQueued again.

Now, I am migrating the code to X C Binding (XCB).
There is a blocking function "xcb_wait_for_event" which is fine for reading an event.
What I miss is some function "peeking ahead" if there are events pending,
WITHOUT actually returning/removing the event from the queue.

I was reading the web for a couple of hours now, but am not able to find such a function.
The "xcb_poll_for_event" does not help. Blocking is fine for me,
since my event detection runs in its own thread.
The "xcb_request_check" as third input function does not seem to be what I want.

Could somebody help me out?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `xcb_poll_for_queued_event(xcb_connection_t *c)` which returns the next event without reading from the connection?

Comment: Ah, I was using the API documentation at: http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/index.html which is of version XCB 1.2 (quite old), but now found newer ones of XCB 1.9. Yes, the xcb_poll_for_queued_event function sounds promising. Will try it out in the next couple of days ...

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks to Julien for his reply.

I have studied the XCB 1.9 sources and found out that the
"xcb_poll_for_queued_event" function is not what I need.

The functions "xcb_poll_for_event" and "xcb_poll_for_queued_event"
both call "poll_for_next_event".
The functions "poll_for_next_event" and "xcb_wait_for_event"
both call "get_event".

If "get_event" finds an event, it changes the internal
linked list to point to the next event. However, I would
prefer NOT to change the event queue AT ALL, independent
from whether or not events are available.

I therefore propose to add a function like the following to XCB:

```
void* NULL_POINTER = (void*) 0;

int xcb_test_for_event(xcb_connection_t* c) {

    int r = 0;

    if (c != NULL_POINTER) {

        struct _xcb_in in = c->in;
        struct event_list* l = in.events;

        if (l != NULL_POINTER) {

            xcb_generic_event_t* e = l->event;

            if (e != NULL_POINTER) {

                r = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

This would allow me to write an endless loop like:

```
while (!xcb_test_for_event(connection)) {

    sleep(t);
}
```

This is comparable to the old Xlib function:

```
int n = XEventsQueued(d, QueuedAfterReading);
```

which just checked the number of events in the event queue.
The "XEventsQueued" function always returns immediately WITHOUT
input/output, if there are events already in the queue.

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to send this to xcb@lists.freedesktop.org to discuss this!