# XEventsQueued equivalent in xcb

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib, xcb

I have read '[Need for XEventsQueued(display, QueuedAfterReading) in XCB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775281/need-for-xeventsqueueddisplay-queuedafterreading-in-xcb)' but the answer specifies a function (`xcb_poll_for_queued_event`) that modifies the internal event queue. I need a function that is **exactly** the equivalent of `XEventsQueued(display, QueuedAfterReading)`.

Modifying the event queue breaks the code I'm currently writing if done where `XEventsQueued` would be used.

What is the equivalent function or block of code in xcb?