# XCB equivalent of XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat

Tags: x11, xcb

I was running code from a separate thread, so couldn't call any Xlib functions, I can only call XCB. I was wondering what the equivalent for `XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat` would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCB presents a more direct view of the protocol than Xlib does, so you often have to look at either the protocol specs or Xlib source code to find out what the underlying protocol request is to find an equivalent.

In this case, [the Detectable Autorepeat section of the XKB extension spec](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/kbproto/xkbproto.html#Detectable_Autorepeat) says it uses the *XkbPerClientFlags* request, which in turn maps to the [`xcb_xkb_per_client_flags()` function](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/group__XCB__xkb__API.html#gaedd24e0582df91f640566d187b2162fb).  Unfortunately, there's no documentation written for this xcb function yet, so you have to use the details from the XKB extension spec and [the code for the Xlib implementation](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/xkb/XKB.c?id=libX11-1.6.4#n520) to work out the right arguments.

Comment: Thanks very much alanc for this solution, this was bothering me very much! I'll look at the XKB spec and will add to here what I learn. :)